# How can i uninstall app by using email id from play store programmatically in android?

Tags: android, email, uninstallation, google-play

I just want to know that is it possible to uninstall android apps from other app which installed on other phone by particular email id. so my concern is using that email id i will come to know that how many app installed on my phone using email id.  get these app programmatically and uninstall from your account from other app. pls advise if there is any way to do it.

thanks.

Comment: You will have better luck using an Android developer support site in a language that is more comfortable for you. I list several such sites at http://www.andglobe.com.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling apps without user confirmation is not possible via 3rd party apps in Android as it would be a security violation.